# Getting ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR from order_as_specified gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `order_as_specified` gem, to order my records in a custom order

```
reach_order = [3,1,67,43,...]
influencers = Influencer.order_as_specified(id: reach_order)
```

**reach_order** array length is around 2000 entries.

Now I am getting `PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR: target lists can have at most 1664 entries` error.

Is this the right way to do a query with custom order ids? Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: I believe you are sending a lot of entries to postgres, how about adding pagination.

Comment: @Saad Is it possible to order_by a custom list without using any other gems? Using pure active record queries?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [find_with_order](https://github.com/khiav223577/find_with_order) gem.

```
reach_order = [3,1,67,43,...]
influencers = Influencer.where_with_order(:id, reach_order)
```

It works fine with no matter how large your ids array is.